# What would cause water to flow around the toilet flange where the concrete is?

Tags: plumbing, toilet

My toilet was leaking around the bottom so I assumed that it needed a wax ring. However when I removed the toilet, after emptying the water,  I noticed that water keeps coming up around the flange.

What causes this and how can I fix it?

Comment: So the water is coming up between the flange and the floor? Is the toilet located in a basement, on ground level, or on an upper floor?

Comment: Wendy, I'll add a bounty to this question if you answer @pdd's comment.  We need more information.

Comment: VTC, NARQ as we're not getting any feedback from OP.